# Java custom non-checked Throwable

Tags: java, ruby, throwable

I just wanna reimplement Ruby's `catch-throw` structure in Java.

The `catch-throw` structure is like

```
catch :halt do
  loop do  # an infinite loop
    puts 'foo'
    throw :halt
  end
end
```

The message `foo` is printed only once. The essence is that what you `throw` is not an exception, so it survives all `rescue`s and propagates the call stack until you `catch` it.

In Java, I know there is the class `java.lang.Throwable` which has two built-in subclasses `java.lang.Exception` and `java.lang.Error`. What I need is a custom class, say `Halt` that directly inherits `Throwable`, which means it's neither a common `Exception` that could be caught by third-party libraries or frameworks, nor an `Error` which may affect tests. `Halt` needs to be non-checked so that I don't have to add `throws Halt` in the method declarations or a forced `try-catch`. How can I define such class?

Comment: Do you really want to create such a class or do you want to create a way to exit a loop?

Comment: Okay. The need is to halt a database stream handling and close the stream when some condition is met. For some reason, the handler method is of type `void` and I just can't tell the lib to `break` its loop.

Comment: You could extend `RuntimeException` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) which is unchecked. But ultimately it needs to be caught, which you seem to be planning to do anyway.

Comment: @d.j.brown I need a `Throwable` that's not an `Exception` because the lib simply catches all exceptions and wraps them in its own exception class then re-throws them.

Comment: @Aetherus I don't think this is possible "For the purposes of compile-time checking of exceptions, `Throwable` and any subclass of `Throwable` that is not also a subclass of either `RuntimeException` or `Error` are regarded as checked exceptions." and "Only objects that are instances of this class [`Throwable`] (or one of its subclasses) are thrown by the Java Virtual Machine or can be thrown by the Java `throw` statement" (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html)

Comment: Now I feel it was a wrong decision to not bring `goto` to Java :)